# Solrcloud service keeps on restarting when created using NSSM

Tags: solrcloud, nssm

I'm trying to setup SOLR Cloud to work with my Sitecore 9.0 (Update-1) instance. I'm using 3 different VMs with [1-Zookeeper + 1-SOLR 6.6.2] configured on all machines.
we use following parameters for creating solrcloud service using NSSM

"start -cloud -p 8983 -z (servername):2181 -noprompt"

If I see in **services.msc** it is running all the time.
But when I see event logs it shows service stopped and started every minute.
same command working fine if executed from CMD.

Does the command I use is correct to create Solrcloud Nssm service?

Answer (score 0):

One of my workmates had this issue. Solution to this is adding -f parameter. [This page](http://coding-art.blogspot.com/2016/07/running-solr-61-as-windows-service.html) describes its purpose.